# Unity WaitForSeconds waits more than expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

When I complete the level, it must show 'Level Completed!" text and wait for 5 seconds then start next level.

```
private void showSuccess() {
         levelCompleted.SetActive (true);
         StartCoroutine("waitForNextLevel");
}

IEnumerator waitForNextLevel() {
         Debug.Log ("Start time: " + Time.time);
         yield return new WaitForSeconds (5);
         Debug.Log ("End time: " + Time.time);
         prepareTheLevel ();
}
```

However, the text appears successfully, the game waits for 5 seconds, and the text dissappears. Then it waits another 5 seconds and start the next level.

I want it wait only 5 seconds without hiding the text.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you see in Console (right click on Console tab -> `Open Editor Log` will give you text output)? Could you also post result of `Debug.Log(Time.timeScale);` (e.g. do it in `waitForNextLevel()`)? What does method `prepareTheLevel()` contain?

Comment: prepareTheLevel() does hide the text 'Level Completed!'  and starts level from beginning. I saw the Unity executes the first Debug.Log over and over during 5 seconds, then it executes the second Debug.Log over and over during another 5 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have something along the lines of:

```
if (playerScore > winScore)
    showSuccess();
```

on a game object somewhere.

If this is the case, `showSuccess` is being called every frame, and each time it creates a new coroutine that starts the next level in 5 seconds. When the first one finishes, the level is destroyed (which removes the text) and the next level starts loading - but you have 5 seconds worth of coroutines stacked up, so roughly every frame it's calling `prepareTheLevel` again until you run out of active coroutines.

Your solution to guard it with a bool is pretty close to what you should do, but misses the underlying problem of stacking up 5 seconds worth of coroutines - I'd recommend guarding the call to `StartCoroutine` instead - you could even use the active flag on the levelCompleted text, i.e:

```
private void showSuccess() {
    if (levelCompleted.IsActive() == false) {
        levelCompleted.SetActive (true);
        StartCoroutine("waitForNextLevel");
    }
}
```

This will make it so the second call to `showSuccess` will see that `levelCompleted` is active, and do nothing, leaving you with only one `waitForNextLevel` coroutine like you want.

Comment: Your approach is right. showSuccess() method was called by another method which is running on Update(). I put a if clause which is preventing the method being called in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've solved my issue as always. However it is not satisfying for me. I saw Unity executes the code below the WaitForLevel method over and over for 5 seconds. Why does it do this like that? :S

The code below solved my issue

```
private bool isWaited = false;

IEnumerator waitForNextLevel() {
         Debug.Log ("Start time: " + Time.time);
         yield return new WaitForSeconds (5);
         Debug.Log ("End time: " + Time.time);
         if (!isWaited) {
            prepareTheLevel ();
            isWaited = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: it is doing almost the same thing what Tasgall has proposed. In your solution waitForNextLevel is getting called over and over again, thats why you have to put a check "isWaited". I will suggest you to use Tasgall solution, which will be more robust.